# Installable Trigger or Manifest Trigger for Google Sheets AddOn Making BigQuery Request

Tags: google-apps-script, google-bigquery, google-workspace-add-ons

I am trying to use Google Big Query in my App Script for a Google Workspace AddOn I have created.  In my dev environment this all works fine as a separate function with a static query, however I need to make the queries dynamic based on values users set in particular cells of a particular sheet.  To do this I think I need to use `onEdit()` type functionality.

However the documentation makes clear that I can’t use onEdit to make such requests that require authorisation so I need to use a trigger and this is where I am getting confused.

Looking at the docs for [installable triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)  this seems to be the way to go.  However at the bottom re [triggers in add-ons](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#installable_triggers_in_add-ons) it says I need to follow a different method and points me to [Manifest Triggers](https://developers.google.com/workspace/add-ons/concepts/gsuite-triggers#installable_triggers).  However, at the bottom of [Manifest Triggers section](https://developers.google.com/workspace/add-ons/concepts/gsuite-triggers#manifest_triggers) it then says `In addition to manifest triggers, Google Workspace Add-ons can also use Apps Script installable triggers` which takes me back to where I came from.

So do I need to use Manifest Triggers for an Add On or can I use an installable trigger via App Script? Or can I use either but certain use cases would suggest one over the other?

Comment: You should use an installable Edit trigger.

Comment: That's great thanks @Aerials.  That's the route I decided to take.